# reading vector Binary File

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a class that reads and writes from a binary file.

My problem here is with my template function, I need to be able to read a vector but also check if it is a class, if its a class I need to call the class read else just read the in file.

```
template <class T>
void VecRead(istream& in, T& vector)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    in.read((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
    vector.resize(size);

    for (auto &element : vector)
    {
        // need to check if its a class here
        if (Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type)
            element.read(in);
        else
            in.read((char*)&element, sizeof(T));
    }
}

class Student
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    vector<int> grades;
    void read(istream& in)
    {
        readString(in, name);
        in.read((char*)&age, sizeof(int));
        VecRead(in, grades);
    }
};

class File
{
public:
    Header header;
    vector<Student> students;
    void read(const char* fileName)
    {
        std::ifstream in(fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        header.read(in);
        VecRead(in, students);
        in.close();
    }
};
```

Comment: I _think_ I see what you meant. But having a function that does 2 completely different things doesn't sound good.

Comment: Of course `T` is a class type. (it's iterable, and it's not an array, AFAIK)  Did you mean `T::value_type`?

Comment: I have been trying for almost three days to find a question with a proper [MCVE].

Comment: @JiveDadson [Hopefully useful](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a2%20is%3aq).

Answer (score 1):

According to what you are trying to do I would suggest to check if `T` has correct method `read`, instead of just checking if it is a class.

In order to make this check you can create a class that would check if `T` has any kind of method named `read` and then check it`s signature. This could be done with a code like this:

```
template<class CC>
class HasReadFunc
{
    template <class C>
    static constexpr bool test_( decltype(&C::read) )
    {
        return std::is_same<
                   decltype(&C::read),
                   void(C::*)(istream&)
                >::value;
    }
    template <class C>
    static constexpr bool test_(...) { return false; }
public:
    static constexpr const bool value = test_<CC>(nullptr);
};
```

The first check is made with the use of SFINAE, the second - simply `std::is_same`

This class could be used like:

```
if( HasReadFunc<T>::value ) ...
```

And this Does work for basic types.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::is_class`. `is_class<T>::value` checks if `T` is a class type. If so, the value is `true`.

But however, whatever you use, you can't complie your code successfully if you just fill the if condition.

Yes, `std::is_class<T>::value` is a literal. It can be checked at complie time. However, `if statement` can't, including `if constexpr`. **They can't avoid the complier compling the statements inside if statement.**

So, the only way I can think to solve this problem is to define two functions. One is class-type parameter version. The other is non-class-type one.

Comment: And std::is_class is defined in <type_traits> and must use a complier supporting C++11 or higher.

Comment: problem is my function fails to build "left of '.read' must have class/struct/union"

Comment: @wihutamiz Of course, if statement can't check it before complie.

Comment: is there any way this can be done before compile time then?

Comment: `if constexpr` (c++17)

Comment: @wihutamiz And why don't you define two function then use is_class to ensure calling which function?

Comment: because i thought it looks better in one class, plus less code

Comment: @wihutamiz then try it.

Comment: By the way -- you can [edit] the answer to add more information.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for your big help, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to disambiguate the argument inside the function, consider using an overloaded function to let the compiler do the work for you:

```
void readElement(istream& in, Student& target)
{
    target.read(in);
}

void readElement(istream& in, int target)
{
    in.read((char*)&target, sizeof(int));
}


template <class T>
void VecRead(istream& in, T& vector)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    in.read((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
    vector.resize(size);

    for (auto &element : vector)
    {
        readElement(in, element);
    }
}
```

The above only handles the two cases presented (and if those are the only ones, I would advise against breaking out templates). However, if you want this to work with several types, template specialization + SFINAE is the way to go:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_trivial_v<T>> readElement(istream& in, T& target)
{
    in.read((char*)&target, sizeof(T));
}

template <class T>
void readElement(istream& in, T& target)
{
    target.read(in);
}
```

This reads in *trivial types* directly and calls `.read()` on everything else. You will get a compile time error when the target type is not trivial and has no `read()` method, which is good because the intended behavior in that case is not clear.

---

PS: If you expect that the `vector` argument to `VecRead` is always a vector, you should make that explicit:

```
template <class T>
void VecRead(istream& in, std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    in.read((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
    vector.resize(size);

    for (auto &element : vector)
    {
        readElement(in, element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note of caution: OP wants to separate class types and built-in types, and some trivial types are also class types. In particular, a trivial class with pointer members will break this, even if it has a `read` member function.